# Integration by parts using u-substitution and square root

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to use the technique of integration by parts to evaluate the integrals. I'm having trouble with a particular problem:

$$
\int x (\sqrt{x+2}) dx
$$

I'm using u-substitution, but since I'm also integrating by parts, my "u-substitution" will be using the variable "g"

$g=x+2$

$\frac {dg}{dx} = 1 dx = dx$

Now the original problem is:

$$
\int x (\sqrt{g}) dx = \int x g^\frac 12 dx
$$

So, I begin integrating by parts:

$$
= (x)(\frac 23 g^\frac 32) -\int (\frac 23 g^\frac 32)(dx)
$$

I take out the constant, then find the integral:

$$
= (x)(\frac 23 g^\frac 32) - (\frac 23) (\frac 25 g^\frac 52) + C
$$

Which then gives me:

$$
= (\frac {2x}3 g^\frac 32) - (\frac 4{15} g^\frac 52) + C
$$

This is where I'm stuck, and I feel that I've missed an early step in the substitution (something to do with x = u - 1?).

The answer I should eventually arrive at is:

$$
= \frac 2{15} (x+2)^\frac 32 (3x-4)+C
$$

Comment: If $g = x + 2$ then $g - 2 = x$ so your integral becomes $$\int (g - 2) \sqrt{g} \ \ dg$$ not $$\int x \sqrt{g} \ \  dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just perform an integration by parts:
$$
\begin{align}
\int x (\sqrt{x+2}) dx&=x \:\frac 23 (x+2)^\frac 32-\frac 23\int  (x+2)^\frac 32 dx\\\\
&=x \:\frac 23 (x+2)^\frac 32-\frac 23 \times\frac 25(x+2)^\frac 52 +C\\\\
&=\frac 23 x(x+2)^\frac 32-\frac 4{15}(x+2)^\frac 52 +C\\\\
&=\left(\frac 23 x-\frac 4{15}(x+2)\right)(x+2)^\frac 32 +C\\\\
&=\left(\color{red}{\frac 2{15}}\times5 x-\color{red}{\frac {2\color{black}{\times 2}}{15}}(x+2)\right)(x+2)^\frac 32 +C\\\\
&=\color{red}{\frac 2{15}}\left[\color{blue}{5x-2(x+2)}\right](x+2)^\frac 32 +C\\\\
&=\color{red}{\frac 2{15}}\left(\color{blue}{5x-2x-4}\right)(x+2)^\frac 32 +C\\\\
& =\frac 2{15} (x+2)^\frac 32 (3x-4)+C
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Between your last step (the answer) and the one before it, I'm having a difficult time seeing what was done. Could you please elaborate on that part?

Comment: @WesFoster I've added some details, hoping to be clear. Thanks.

Comment: That is so helpful! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

There really isn't any need for integration by parts.

If $g = x+2$, then $x = g-2$, and as you note, $dg = dx$. So your integral becomes $$\int (g-2)(g^{1/2}) \,dg = \int \left(g^{3/2} - 2g^{1/2}\right)\,dg$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Is finding $x = g - 1$ as simple as solving for $x$ in $g = x + 2$? This part of substitution kept me awake lastnight.

Comment: Yes, but we used $g = x+2$, so to solve for $x$ we just subtract $2$ from each side of the equation to get $x = g-2.$

Comment: Great response! I had to break this problem down into parts, so I chose the other answer. However, this answer is equally as useful, thanks!